# Unity3d - deploy game to android device off site

Tags: unity, android

I am using Unity3d to develop my game and my friend with android device wanted to test it. I am natively IOS developer and have no knowledge of deploying Android platform. What do I need other than Unity3d? The scenario here is that I have to send to my friend who is not developer to install and test on his device via internet. We used to have TestFlight App but that is history now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is the minimum you need:

- You have to install android sdk and set path to it in Unity preferences
- You have to switch target platform to android and set settings you need in Player Settings (like supported android versions etc.)
- Click "build" in Build Settings - if everything is fine you'll get an .apk file that you can send to your friend

But again, you might run into some problems. It depends of your project and your code. For example, if you have some plugin code that works only for iOS (using `[DllImport]` attribute) you might have to turn it off or rewrite for android (using `AndroidJavaClass`, for example). You might also be using some features that are not supported on android.

There might be some other problems, but there is no answer which ones - you should try it and find them out by yourself.

Also, you can test your .apk on android simulator before sending to anyone else (in this case install android studio or eclipse to make it a little more comfortable).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are talking about what is required to deploy to test devices. Luckily, it is significantly easier on Android than it is on iOS. Your tester will have to enable the installation of non-market on their Android device, after which they can just click on a link for an APK and download/install it through their phone's browser. To enable non-market executables, direct them to go to Settings, then Application Settings, and then to enable Unknown Sources. This will allow them to install non-market executables. If this is not suitable for your purposes, you can also go into the Android Marketplace portal and create your application, and from there you can add testers to your app. They should then be able to search and install it through the Android marketplace, but it will not be visible for users who are not in your app profile until after it has been officially released.